# Installing Imagemagick on 1and1

Tags: server, imagemagick, hosting

I am trying to install ImageMagick on my 1and1 shared hosting, they say it is possible however you need to use their pre-installed version, but are unable to give me instructions or tell me how to do this.

So does anyone know how to get and install the pre-installed imagemagick on 1and1?

Thank you

Comment: Any good? https://help.1and1.com/hosting-c37630/webspace-and-access-c85098/ssh-c37775/install-imagemagick-via-ssh-a649013.html

Comment: Sadly not, 1and1 said themselves this does not work and that you need to use their pre-installed version. Just won't advise how!

Comment: `hostgator.com` are good...